# Definitions of the Catalogs in Maven

Tags: maven

[New Maven Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tps0W.png)

Above I attached the screenshot of the interface you see when you try to create a new **Maven Project** in **Eclipse IDE**. In here we can see the catalog dropdown with a list. I like to know what are those in detail. For example, I'm not sure of what they mean by *Internal*. Any source I could look up?

Comment: These are the catalogs set up in the m2e preferences in Eclipse. Go to Window -> Preferences -> "Maven" to look them up.